# Is there any permutation $\tau\in S_7$ so that: $\tau^{4}=\sigma$?

Tags: group-theory, permutations

Let $\tau$ be a permutation in $S_7$: 
$\
  \sigma=
  \left(
  \begin{matrix}
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4&5&6&7\\
    3 & 4 & 5 &6&1&7&2 \
  \end{matrix}
  \right)
\
$
is there any permutation $\tau\in S_7$ so that: $\tau^{4}=\sigma$?

ATTEMPT:
$\
  \
  \left(
  \begin{matrix}
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7\\
    ? & ? & ? & ? & ? & ? & ? \  
\end{matrix}
  \right)^{4}=\
\
$
$\
  \sigma=
  \left(
  \begin{matrix}
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4&5&6&7\\
    3 & 4 & 5 &6&1&7&2 \
  \end{matrix}
  \right)
\
$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\sigma = (135)(2467)$ so $\sigma$ is an odd permutation. Clearly, for every $\tau$, $\tau^4$ is an even permutation. Hence is imposible to have
$$\tau^4 = \sigma$$

Answer (score 1):

For $k=1,2,3,4,5,6,7$, what happens if you take the fourth power of a $k$-cycle?

What cycles appear in $\sigma$?

Answer (score 1):

$\sigma$ has order $12$,so $\tau$ should have order $48$, $\tau^3$ order $16$. A permutation of order $p^k$ has at least one cycle of length $p^k$